# keras dosen't load the model and weights when using checkpoint

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, data-science, checkpoint

I'm using keras to build a deep autoencoder. I used its checkpointer to load the model and the weights but the result is always `None` which I think it means that the checkpoint dosen't work correctly and is not saving weights.
Here is the code how I proceed:

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="weights.best.h5",
                               verbose=0,
                               save_best_only=True)
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder',
                          histogram_freq=0,
                          write_graph=True,
                          write_images=True)
input_enc = Input(shape=(input_size,))
hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_size1, activation='relu')(input_enc)
hidden_11 = Dense(hidden_size2, activation='relu')(hidden_1)
code = Dense(code_size, activation='relu')(hidden_11)
hidden_22 = Dense(hidden_size2, activation='relu')(code)
hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_size1, activation='relu')(hidden_22)
output_enc = Dense(input_size, activation='tanh')(hidden_2)
autoencoder_yes = Model(input_enc, output_enc)

autoencoder_yes.compile(optimizer='adam',
                         loss='mean_squared_error', 
                         metrics=['accuracy'])
history_yes = autoencoder_yes.fit(df_noyau_norm_y, df_noyau_norm_y,
                               epochs=200,
                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                shuffle = True,
                                validation_data=(df_test_norm_y, df_test_norm_y),
                                verbose=1, 
                                callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard]).history

autoencoder_yes.save_weights("weights.best.h5")
print(autoencoder_yes.load_weights("weights.best.h5"))
```

Can somebody help me find out a way to resolve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, your interpretation of `load_weights` returning None is not correct. Load weights is a procedure, it does not return anything, and if you assign the return value of a procedure to a variable, it will get the value of None.

So weight saving is probably working fine, its just your interpretation that is wrong.

Comment: Ok, so how can I access to the file containing the weights and re-used another time?? And I want to know: if the weights are correctly saved is it necessary to keep the script of the training process of the autoencoder because I'm working in the same file and I don't want each time I run the script the autoencoder starts training again ??

Comment: @Mari You just use load_model to load the model and weights from a .hdf5 file.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `save_weights_only=True`. Without this the whole model is saved not just the weights. To be able to load weights you must save weights like this:

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="weights.best.h5",
                           verbose=0, save_weights_only=True,
                           save_best_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior not an error. The `autoencoder_yes.load_weights("weights.best.h5")` doesn't actually return anything, so if you try to print the output of this function you *will* get `None` as output.

**Expected behavior**

In the code that you have provided, you have trained the model and saved the weights. So, the `autoencoder_yes` is a `keras.Model` object that has the fine-tuned weights.

In the same script if you load the saved weights once again, nothing is supposed to happen, the weights that you saved will get loaded again.

**For clarity**

Start with another fresh script, build the same model architecture and reload the weights from the `h5` file and then do some predictions. In that case it will silently load the pre-trained weights and do the predictions according to that.

Comment: Ok, so how can I access to the file containing the weights and re-used another time?? And I want to know: if the weights are correctly saved is it necessary to keep the script of the training process of the autoencoder because I'm working in the same file and I don't want each time I run the script the autoencoder starts training again ??

Comment: No you dont need the training script at all. In the separate script (usually the test script or predict script), just don't `fit` the model, do everything that you have done and load the weights directly from the `h5` file instead of calling the `fit` function

Comment: I understand it. But the problem now is that when I load the weights to get the encoded data layer (since I'm working on autoencoder) to do some operations on it, I get different results each time which I think it means that the weights are not fixed and saved correctly ! Do you have any explanation and solution for that ?